# S3 file hosting sub-directory with domains

Tags: amazon-s3

i would like to use S3 for file hosting. I want to use a single bucket for all of this. (important note)

In a bucket I would like to have a folder that is mapped to a domain. so something like this

acct/bucketname/folder1/file1
acct/bucketname/folder2/file2

I want to map

folder1.com to acct/bucketname/folder1
and 
folder2.com to acct/bucketname/folder2

This way I don't end up with assets from one folder being addressable in the other domain name.

Note: the reason I don't want to use buckets for this is because of the 50 bucket per acct limit.

Answer (score 2):

Not presently, due to some important details about S3:

1. You can do a 1:1 mapping between a CNAME and a bucket, because buckets are DNS-addressable.
2. S3 does not have folders. S3 is a flat hierarchy of files inside of a bucket. Filenames allow `/` characters in them. Many UIs for S3 display these as folders, but that's a made-up concept.